# Passing variable to a django queryset

Tags: mysql, django, django-rest-framework, join

So I have this urlset below. And in the urlset there are two urls that take paramters into the url and passes it into the apiviw.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/test/$', views.DuperView.as_view()),
    url(r'^test/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/$', views.SuperView.as_view()),
    url(r'^test/', views.TestView.as_view()),
]
```

Here is the APIView that everything is passed into.

```
class DuperView(APIView):
    queryset = models.DuperModel.dupers.duperdeduper()

    def get(self, request, year, month, format=None):
        an_apiview = [
            year,
            month,
            ]

        return Response({'http_method': 'GET', 'api_view': an_apiview})
```

the first parameter that is defined in the url as ([0-9]{4}) is passed into the get method as year and the second defined as ([0-9]{1,2}) is passed as month.

Here is my model, model manager and model queryset for the model this all corresponds to.

```
class DuperQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def duperdeduper(self):
        return self.filter(year='2000')

class DuperModelManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return DuperQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def duperdeduper(self):
        return self.get_queryset().authors()

class DuperModel(models.Model):
    year = models.ForeignKey(YearModel)
    month = models.ForeignKey(MonthModel)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    dupers = DuperModelManager()
```

I was wondering if there is a way to pass the year and month parameters to the model somehow, that way I can use it when I process the data in the models?

```
SELECT * FROM dupertable, yeartable WHERE year='variablevaluepassedon'
```

Is this kind of functionality possible? I know I can use the .filter() method on my queryset, but my problem is getting the variable to the queryset to make this query work.

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking here. You can pass parameters to the queryset by overriding the `get_queryset` method in the view; is that what you mean?

Comment: No I cannot modify the get_queryset method for my needs. Lets say the URL requested is "/api/1234/12/test/". I need to pass the 1234 and the 12 into the model to process some data. So somehow I need to get those exact values from the URL to the APIView and then from the APIView to the Model. I want the query to take those two values go to a database and check for them (and since those two values are foreign keys) I then would get the data from both models/database tables pertaining to that data.

Comment: I can't see how that relates at all to the code you've posted. You originally talked about month and year, so why can't you do `DuperModel.dupers.filter(month=self.kwargs['month], year=self.kwargs['year'])`? What other models are you talking about?

Comment: So when I use the filter method I can pass those into the model? also is self.kwargs in the apiview? I want to know more about kwargs.

Comment: But I don't understand what you mean by "pass those into the model"? Pass what, where - and do what with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Daniel mentionnned, you should just override the get_queryset method from your view. From there you can pass your parameters you got from the url.

```
class DuperView(GenericApiView, ListModelMixin):

    def get_queryset(self):
        year = self.kwargs.get('year')
        month = self.kwargs.get('month')

        return DuperModel.dupers.filter(month=month, year=year)
```

I have used the GenericApiView to add the get_queryset method. You can then add the mixins you need for your API. In this case, I added the ListModelMixin, that implement a get method to retrieve a list of elements.

Also you should reference your parameter in your urls :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9][0-9]{1,2})/test/$', 
]
```

Comment: A listapiview is read-only, would this work with a standard apiview?

Comment: I don't know about apiview. I usually used GenericAPIView which inherit from Apiview.

Comment: So since GenericAPIView inherits from APIView do I just implement get, post, put, etc. in my DuperView?

Comment: With GenericApiView, part of the logic is implemented into mixins that (CreateModelMixin, ListModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin, UpdateModelMixin and DestroyModelMixin) that use the get, post, put,etc  and plug them with the extra methods added by GenericApiView.

Comment: So would I have to make the extra generic apiviews? I looked at that page yesterday when you mentioned GenericAPIView but I was completely lost. I'll read it instead of skimming it like I did yesterday.

Comment: I suggest you use these mixins if you have a simple API logic. If you still need to implement the get,post, put method, you should take a look at the source code of the mixins I mentionned before. They are quite simple and can be used as a base for what you want to do.

Here is the link to the doc:  http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/

Comment: we can move this to the chat if you want more infos on this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147464/discussion-between-f-caron-and-joshua-blevins).